# What is a more accurate name for "Full-spectrum" photography?

Tags: light, infrared, infrared-conversion, visible-light

Photography enthusiasts (and [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Full-spectrum_photography)) often call photography that happens outside of the visible spectrum *full-spectrum photography*.

From a scientific standpoint, however, I do not believe that these cameras indeed capture the "full" spectrum - or that there is such a thing in the consumer market. They do not capture X-Rays or Gamma rays, and other wavelengths like far infrared or ultraviolet are probably left out too.

**Is there a better, scientifically accurate way to call a camera that has been converted to capture wavelengths that are outside of the visible spectrum, or this type of photography?**

Comment: Why are you searching for an alternate phrase?

Comment: "Full*er*-spectrum" photography?

Comment: I seriously doubt that we have the technology to create sensors that capture the _entire_ electromagnetic spectrum...

Comment: @xiota I often talk about the type of photography that I do with scientists and they correct me *everytime* I say "full-spectrum".

Comment: "Full-spectrum-_ish_, depending on the pedantry of the person you're talking with"?

Comment: @scottbb (good) scientists are usually rigorous with language

Comment: Clear communication isn't about being "rigorous" with language. It's about using language appropriate for the context.  The word "fundamental" has different meaning to physicists then it does to anyone.  It's ridiculous to insist on the physics usage in non-physics contexts.  Similarly for "proof", which has different meanings in mathematics, science, law, etc.

Comment: @xiota Are you saying that it is acceptable for a plebeian to say “joke was so good I *literally died*”? Cause I don’t.

Comment: "Literally" has no such *accepted* literal usage in any field I'm aware of, unless it is the person's ghost speaking.  Usually, the speaker is exaggerating for effect.  Regardless of the adverb chosen, the statement is fiction.  Literally died, nearly died, died laughing, etc.  No reasonable person believes any of it happened.

Comment: [Irregardless](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irregardless), [I could care less](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/could_care_less#English). This is [literally](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/literally) the worst thing, ever. But [that begs the question](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Begging_the_question#Contemporary_usage)...

Comment: @scottbb "begs the question" – the "correct" usage is based on a "mistranslation of the Latin petitio principii"?! // "you literally become the ball" – The giants kick you around in a game of football. // "she was literally in floods of tears" – Alice in Wonderland?

Comment: @xiota Language is weird, eh? ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every field of study and practice has established terminology and usage. It generally does not make sense to apply the jargon of one to another. For instance, suppose you take photos with a "720nm" bandpass filter. "720nm" may be considered a misnomer because some shorter wavelengths and most longer wavelengths are allowed through. But for the sake of efficiency of communication, it's sufficient to refer to them as 720nm filters. Those who are interested may refer to the transmission charts.

[Full-Spectrum Photography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Full-spectrum_photography) adequately communicates the concept of light capture beyond the visible and is understood by most people. The use of the word *Photography* excludes wavelengths that are generally not considered to be light, such as X-rays, gamma rays, and heat. The recording of other spectra often have their own specific terms, such as *radiography*.

Some options to consider:

- **Visible and Near Infrared** ([VNIR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VNIR)). String together the specific spectra you're interested in. UV + V + NIR + ETC.
- **Specify the nominal wavelengths** of the filters. Wonder why scientists don't object that the filters are imperfect and allow other wavelengths through.
- **Dual spectrum.** For photography that excludes certain spectra. Examples: blue + IR and UV+IR.
- **Expanded Spectrum**, **Extended Spectrum**, **Broad Spectrum**, etc.
- **NDVI** ([Normalized difference vegetation index](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normalized_difference_vegetation_index)) – For photography used to evaluate plant health.
- **[Ghost Hunting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ghost_hunting)**. I'd consider this phrase, just to see how people respond. If they insist that ghosts don't exist, I'd show them some flare ghosts:

  [image: Sun Star and Flare Ghosts]
- Tell them **it *really* is "full spectrum"**, they just *can't see* all of it.

Comment: Thanks - great answer, I think scientists I talk with would prefer UVNIR to "full-spectrum". I think the camera I use is converted to UV, visible, and IR light, would UVNIR work? Has a nice ring to it 

Comment: I have no idea. Feels kind of like making things up. UVNIR might be considered dual spectrum (no visible)? Perhaps UVVNIR. But some might object that you're not capturing *all* of the [NIR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infrared#Commonly_used_sub-division_scheme) or UV spectra.

Comment: If you merge all channels available into one channel, you might also call it [panchromatic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Panchromatic_film).

Answer (score 1):

You may also find the term 'Hyperspectral' or 'Multispectral' useful. A standard camera producing R,G,B is 'multispectral'.

I don't know if you're attempting to generalize a modified camera (such as removal of the IR cut), but if so multispectral may be more useful.

There is also a camera modified with a variety of 'cut' filters such that each portion receives different wavelengths.

Sensors that can simultaneously provide all wavelengths would be hyperspectral, but the term can be used and abused prodigiously in non-scientific efforts.